# MSI: How to check that product is actually installed

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I have system that install via internet several MSI products and I have a situation - tester delete folder with product, but not the registry keys and my system see that the product exists via registry and it tries to upgrade it, but product actually didn't exists.

Is there any MSI function which help me determinate the state of product in silent mode and if user delete files - uninstall the whole product?

Comment: Current solution - check is main file available. Path to main file stored in registry and removed by MSI

Comment: Not totally sure what you are asking here. I think what you are suggesting is that if the product's application files have been deleted from the system you want to launch the MSI in uninstallation rather than repair mode. I'd suggest you use the MsiGetComponentPath() function to get the component's keypath, and then check whether that file is present. If the file is missing then you use the API to remove rather than upgrade the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just need to check whether the product is still registered with Windows Installer - convert your package's product code to packed guid format (e.g. by using script from http://www.dwarfsoft.com/blog/2010/06/22/msi-package-code-fun/) and search for its presence in  HKCR\Installer\Products.

To actually remove the product from Windows Installer database - the simplest way is to use MsiZap from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370523(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: msizap did exactly what I need, but it is not distributable